# Iterate over DataFrame lines in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dataframe

I want to iterate over `df` and change value in `df2`. If the value of `A` and `B` in `df` is equal to `A` and `B` in `df2` then `C` in `df` is equal to  `C+E/2` of `df2`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('final.csv',names=['A','B','C','D'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('final.csv',names=['A','B','C','D','E'])
for x in df2:
    z=x.loc['A','B']
    df.loc['A','B']
    a=df[['C']]
```

Comment: Please remove the caps. It hurts to read this.

Comment: MegaIng.caps removed

Comment: May I ask why would you be reading the same csv file twice to two separate DataFrames? If it is the same file, then your condition check for `A` and `B` in both DataFrames will always hold `True`.